# Cannot turn on Wifi. MAC address unavailable

Tags: wi-fi, mac-address

I have an Android 4.0.4 tablet, Navon Platinum Explorer.

When I try to turn on wifi, the toggle button goes "off" after a few seconds automatically.
It doesnt even show the list of available networks.

In Wifi-Advanced, there is MAC Address - Unavailable.

The Wifi worked before doing a factory reset.
I also tried turning the table off and on, but it did not help.

What can I do to make the wifi work again?
I do not want to root the tablet.

Comment: At least related: [Stuck on “Turning Wi-Fi on…”](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46077/16575)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why,

but rebooting second time and trying to turn off/on the wifi icon on the homescreen several times did finally work.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue after I flashed a new kernel to my HTC Vivid. My Wi-Fi always showed "Turning on" but never did, and my MAC address showed "Unavailable".

Turns out the problem was as simple as a faulty file in the Android system.

1. Try finding and replacing the file named `bcmdhb.ko` located in `/system/lib/modules`. (You'll need root access and a root file explorer)
2. Download the appropriate file for your phone, boot your phone into recovery/fastboot and plug it into your computer.
3. Now using CMD and [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) enter the command:

   ```
   adb push /users/<USER_NAME>/Desktop/bcmdhd.ko /system/lib/modules
   ```

   (replace `<USERNAME>` with your username in computer)

   To save time, I moved all my ADB files to the same folder as my `bcmdhb.ko` and any other phone related file `boot.img`'s, and more.
4. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click a random spot inside the folder and select the option "Open Command Window Here". That starts your CMD operation right from the location you need, rather than ever having to `cd` to that location.

   Note that doing the shortcut I mentioned does not mean you only type `adb push bcmdhd.ko`. You still need to tell CMD what location to push the file too. So you still have to type `adb push bcmdhd.ko /system/lib/modules`.

Comment: You wrote "Quoted" at the end. I assume you forgot to mention the source from where you learned these steps. Please mention it now.

Answer (score 0):

The app [Blade Wifi Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bladewififix) fixes this issue on a lot of phones.